# Sum of values in html table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML table

[image]

Now I want to display sum of hours to the last column.

I tried like this, its not worked for me.

**HTML**

```
<table class='Table'>
    <tr><td><span class='hours'>8:16</span></td><td><span class='hours'>8:27</span></td><td><span class='hours'>7:30</span></td><td>Print Sum of duration of this Row</td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class='hours'>6:53</span></td><td><span class='hours'>8:02</span></td><td><span class='hours'>8:17</span></td><td>Print Sum of duration of this Row</td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class='hours'>8:09</span></td><td><span class='hours'>8:28</span></td><td><span class='hours'>8:42</span></td><td>Print Sum of duration of this Row</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".Table tr td .hours").each(function(){
    vals1=$(this).html()
    console.log(vals1)
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("td:last").html(vals1)
})
```

From the above code I am unable to determine end of row(TR).
Would be helpful if any suggestion to find sum of duration.

Comment: from the image alone we cant determine the end of row either show html mark up  :)

Comment: `$(".Table tr:has(td .hours)").html(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(this).find('.Table tr td .hours').each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).text() || 0;
  });
  $(this).find("td:last").html(sum)
})
`

Comment: @guradio Now I added HTML part

Comment: There is no element with the class `.hours`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Your code works well.Do you have an idea to find sum of durations (like 10:35+2:35 = 13:10)

Comment: @RinoRaj Sorry I updated my question again

Comment: you'll have to split the 'hh:mm' into two parts, and sum up the minutes and hours separately. `var summ = ...; while(summ >= 60) {sumh +=1; summ -=60;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over each `tr` and find the sum of the fields like

```js
$(".Table tr:has(.hours)").each(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(this).find('td .hours').each(function() {
    var parts = $(this).text().split(':')
    sum += (parts[0] * 60 || 0) + (+parts[1] || 0);
  });
  var mins = Math.floor(sum / 60);
  var sec = sum % 60;
  $(this).find("td:last").html(mins + ':' + ('0' + sec).slice(-2))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='Table'>
  <tr>
    <td><span class='hours'>8:16</span>
    </td>
    <td><span class='hours'>8:27</span>
    </td>
    <td><span class='hours'>7:30</span>
    </td>
    <td>Print Sum of duration of this Row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class='hours'>6:53</span>
    </td>
    <td><span class='hours'>8:02</span>
    </td>
    <td><span class='hours'>8:17</span>
    </td>
    <td>Print Sum of duration of this Row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class='hours'>8:09</span>
    </td>
    <td><span class='hours'>8:28</span>
    </td>
    <td><span class='hours'>8:42</span>
    </td>
    <td>Print Sum of duration of this Row</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```